# Get multiple dynamic class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get multiple classes dynamically using JQuery.
I do something wrong, here is my code -

```
var eventColorSelector = $('.external-event-color-selector_'+id, '.circle_'+id);
```

Please correct this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please update html code,

Comment: Post some helpful HTML code .. from where this `id` is coming from ?

Comment: `$('.external-event-color-selector_'+id + '.circle_'+id);`

Comment: or `$('.external-event-color-selector_'+id + ', .circle_'+id);`

Comment: @Pooja - You need to add more details to your question. The current state will lead to downvotes. Use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/x2Lu8r5L/) as an example to show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try `var eventColorSelector = $('.external-event-color-selector_'+id + ', .circle_'+id);`